# Rest client in python that can map http resource to objects

Tags: python, rest, object, dictionary, client

Are there any REST clients in python that can map HTTP resource (response in JSON) to data objects in python? I looked at [restkit](http://restkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as they claim that they map HTTP resource to python objects but could not find anything in their document about it. I don't mind writing my own mapper, I just wanted to check if there are any I haven't laid my eyes on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mapping a json object to a Python object can be done with the json.load() api

Documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load

Comment: Does it map to user created object? I thought it can only map json object to python dict.

Answer (score 0):

With [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) you have three types of response:

- [binary response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content)
- [json response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content)
- [raw response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content)

I think, that with JSON response it is easier for you to convert or serialize an JSON object into a Python object.